# Simple bootstrap navbar not collapsing on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Perhaps I am missing or not understanding something, however, I have tried everything possible and end up with the same result.

MY PROBLEM

I have dumbed down my page to the point where I simply took the [example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) for a responsive navbar. When I resize my browser window the navbar collapses as it should. [In my JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisChros/1xL2v7uk/) the navbar collapses as it should, however **as soon as I go to a mobile device my navbar is not collapsing**...what am I doing wrong here?

**BROWSER RESIZE**

[image]

Browser resize working as it should!

**MOBILE DEVICE**

[image]

Mobile Device NOT WORKING, why? What Am I doing wrong here? Here is a [link to my JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisChros/1xL2v7uk/)

```
<head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the width of that mobile browser? Maybe the reason of that behaviour is that the `navbar` hasn't reached its breakpoint yet in your mobile device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems to be missing the Viewport tag in your code, double check your code and make sure you have viewport tag available, if not add the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Your JSFiddle example is working fine when its resized to smaller width

Comment: NOOOO...I feel reak stupid now, spend 2-hours debugging and I simply missed a simple meta tag. DOH! Will accept when time expires. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, manimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```